# Kotlin: create list of all dates from inner classes in for loop. find latest date from the list of dates

Tags: java, kotlin

I have a data classes and outer class has list of inner class. I need to create a list of date from the dates available in inner class.

```
data class College(
    val id: Int,
    val isOpen: Boolean,
    val classes: List<Class>?
)

data class Class(
    val id: Int,
    val name: String,
    val students: List<Student>?
)

data class Student(
    val id: Int,
    val name: String?,
    val admissionDate: Date,
    val birthDate: Date
)
```

I want to create the list of all admissionDate to find the latest admissionDate from the list.

How should I create the List of admissionDate from above data classes.
I am having 1 College -> 2 classes -> 2 students in each class -> every student has admissionDate

Finally, Newly created List will be of total 4 date objects and find the earliest date from List.

Comment: [Still using java.util.Date? Don't!](https://programminghints.com/2017/05/still-using-java-util-date-dont/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date is mostly deprecated. You should switch to something like LocalDate. But the following should work even after you switch to a different date type of class.

I also recommend not using `Class` as a class name because `Class` is already a standard library Java class. It has a high likelihood of causing difficulties working with it.

You want to use `flatMap` to create a list of the contents of the lists in each class. But first use `.orEmpty()` so you won't have to deal with its nullability.

You can also use `orEmpty()` on the inner Students list for the same reason.

Then map the students to their admission dates to convert the list of students to a list of admission dates.

Then you can call `min()` on the list to get the earliest date (since dates are Comparable).

```
val dates = college.classes.orEmpty()
    .flatMap { it.students.orEmpty() }
    .map { it.admissionDate }
val earliestDate = dates.min()
```

Edit: In Java:

```java
List<LocalDate> dates = Optional.ofNullable(college.getClasses()).orElse(Collections.emptyList())
        .stream()
        .flatMap(cls -> Optional.ofNullable(cls.getStudents()).orElse(Collections.emptyList()).stream())
        .map(Student::getAdmissionDate)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
LocalDate earliestDate = dates.stream().min(Comparator.naturalOrder()).orElse(null);
```

Comment: Thank you Tenfour04 I am not using Class as Class name for sure :) My classes are different. I have just mocked to show in my question. This works perfect.

Comment: Hi @ Tenfour04 Could you please help in how could I do this for java?

Comment: I added a Java example. I don't use Java streams much, so I don't know if it could be more elegant. @Prashant.J